# getGenericSuperclass() in Java. How does it work?

Tags: java, reflection, jvm

Let's consider the following piece of code:

```
package index;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        Type t = inner.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType p = (ParameterizedType) t;
        Type[] a = p.getActualTypeArguments();
        try {
            Custom c = (Custom) ((Class) a[0]).newInstance();
            c.f();
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }

    private static abstract class AbstractClass<T> {
        public abstract void doSth();
    }
    private static class Inner extends AbstractClass<Custom>{
        public void doSth() {
        }
    }
    private static class Custom{
        public Custom(){

        }
        public void f(){
            System.out.println("Custom");
        }
    }
}
```

1. It works and I cannot understand how does it works. It shows that it is possible to get information about superclasses parameters. I don't know how it is possible to get a such information because I looked at bytecode and there is no such information:
2. Is it ok to do it?

Comment: 1. Read the [`Class.getGenericSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass--) javadoc. 2. Yes.

Comment: What you have shown, is the bytecode of `Main`, not `Inner`, so it can’t tell  you, whether `Inner` has stored its generic super class. To be precise, this isn’t even bytecode, this is the output of a certain byte code processing program. If that program output lacks a certain information, it doesn’t prove that this information is absent in the class file.

Comment: I wish someone would actually answer the question in English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `Signature` attribute in .class file, see [JVMS §4.7.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9).

If you decompile Main.Inner with `javap -verbose`, you'll find this attribute:

```
Signature: #14    // Lindex/Main$AbstractClass<Lindex/Main$Custom;>;
```

[`Class.getGenericSuperclass`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8c93eb3fa1c0/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#l764) implementation extracts this attribute with the help of a [native method](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8c93eb3fa1c0/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#l2528) and then parses, validates and converts it to Java representation. So, it is absolutely possible and OK to get this information.

Comment: Thanks! "So, it is absolutely possible and **OK** to get this information.". But, is it ok in the sense of software engeering?

Comment: @Gilgamesz I'm not sure what you mean by *'the sense of software engineering'*, but yes, this tecnhique is used sometimes. Whether a call to `getGenericSuperclass` is justified or not, depends on the particular use case.